# SharePoint Enterprise Search - Error: OfficeSearch14HealthSession

Tags: 2010, 2013, error, enterprise-search

Ever since I provisioned a dedicated Search & Indexing Server on a SP 2010 production environment , this nagging error occurs everyday as seen in the event viewer of the server:-

> Session "OfficeSearch14HealthSession" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035

I went through a couple of other discussions on [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/sharepoint2010setup/thread/d9580b1b-7cfb-4144-9ee0-529574f06a91) and [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/sharepoint2010general/thread/43f1714c-db30-4904-aae1-086cd09bfd6d) but they all seem to have no comprehensive solution nor an exact understanding of what is causing this error to appear in the event viewer.

Enterprise Search is working *absolutely fine* without any problems. But I cannot seem to get rid of this error. If not an exact solution, I'm hoping someone can share some good pointers towards what may be causing this error.

Comment: Very common, we ignore it in all of our environments that show it.

Comment: This is also very common in SharePoint 2013 environments.

Answer (score 3):

With regards to that particular error code it is linked to Performance Monitor. You could try Make sure the Search Service account is added in the Performance Log Users and afterwards check that you find a search related trace with status Running in "Event Trace Sessions" of the Performance Monitor.